# Reverting back to what you belong to

Tags: expressions, proverbs

I was wondering if there is any fixed expression, poem, proverb to imply:

> Every one who is left far from his source (source= his / her tendencies,) wishes back the time when he was united with it.

I.e. You will always have a tendency to become what you are and not what you are trying to be! So, you will revert back to your essence one day.

For instance:

Please imagine a young person who loves music composing field of working and wants to be a composer at heart. However, despite their feelings, their parents want them to become an engineer.
They may get even a university degree at engineering just because what his/her parents want, but usually, they will revert back to their own interests and probably will work as a composer even as their second job one day! Because this is the field that they belong to and enjoy it.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The quoted part implies wistfulness, while the part immediately following it sounds more fatalistic and related to the idea of destiny - which are you looking to express?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity @Chris Mack. Actually, what I am trying to say has nothing to do with "destiny"! Instead, I am trying to imply "wistfulness" and being far from your 'true self' / 'essence' which ultimately makes you move toward true tendencies. I hope I could make my intention clear.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase that comes to mind would be to say that:

> He/she is a composer **at heart**.

I’m not sure if this satisfies your desire to express them reverting to their core tendencies(?), but it’s certainly what we would say of the person. It does tend to encompass the person’s behaviours, which are in this context presumed to come from what they **are** at their core (“at heart”).

Comment: Well @Chris Mack as you perhaps noticed yourself, unfortunately, this offer does not convey the message in my question through which I need to say: "he/she will finally get back to his own interests".

Comment: @A-friend Can you describe a context/situation in which you’d wish to hear such an expression used?

Comment: I have already described it in my original post @Chris Mack. :) However, I can provide you with another example. First let me bring up another explanation which strikes me as if it can make my meaning clearer. I need to say something like: "he who abides far away from his home, is ever longing for the day he shall return." I.e. "Anyone who's been separated from the Source
Longs for the day of the reunion."

Comment: For instance, a scientific person who loves say chemistry and is temporarily working as a restaurant manager because of some financial problems, may get a good payment, but he/she belongs to somewhere else which is probably a laboratory and his interests will attract him/her to where they belong to.

Comment: @A-friend I understand, but it’s unclear what kind of expression you’re looking for. Are you describing a character in a book? Is it a casual conversation between friends? For example, you could just describe them as feeling “out of place”, but I get the feeling you want something with a bit more gravity to it.

Comment: it is a proverb which can be said in any occasion. As you will probably agree, someone who uses a proverb in speech should have a desirable level of literary knowledge in a language. Also, such a person can evaluate the listener's knowledge. Therefore, it can be said in a casual conversation between friends in an absolutely informal case or in a formal situation when a university professor is talking about another professor to his / her students. It can be said by a TV reporter when it comes to talk about a successful individual who has finally found their right track in life.

Comment: It’s difficult to say. For example, finding one’s right track is different to returning to it, so there’s a clarification of subtleties required here. For finding one’s right track, we might say that one has “found their calling”.